# saving mysql result for multiple output formats

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm running a complex mysql query which takes about 10 minutes to complete. I need to manipulate the selection set in different ways to produce **different output files** based on those manipulations.

Right now I have to run the same where clause multiple times with slight modifications to the overall query depending on desired output. Here's some pseudo code.

```
select * from table where SAME WHERE CLAUSE;
select modification1(field3) from table where SAME WHERE CLAUSE;
select modification3(field1) from table where SAME WHERE CLAUSE;
select modification7(field1,field7) from table where SAME WHERE CLAUSE;
```

Is there a way I could save the query result in memory so I can use it in multiple outputs, then clear it when done? I'm looking for something more efficient than running the same WHERE clause multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS (select * from table where WHERE CLAUSE);
 select modification1(field3) from table2;
 select modification3(field1) from table2;
 select modification7(field1,field7) from table2;
 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE table2;
```

And if you are sure you want the results to be kept in memory, the first line can be:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 ENGINE=MEMORY
     AS (select * from table where WHERE CLAUSE);
```